# Windows service not connecting to database

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, windows-services, timer

I have a windows service. It connects and checks my database every 18seconds before sending out a soap message to an external client. 
I have successfully installed the service on my computer but it is not doing anything in particular nor is it filling my server logs with any errors.

How do I find out where I went wrong?

**Updated**

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Interval = 15000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Windows Service 3 Started");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Windows Service 3 Stopped");

    }
```

My `RunAPP()` is where I have connected to the database via a stored procedure.

Any insight into my problem would be great!

```
  private void RunApp()
    {

        p.Start();
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bbsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            Con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AvailableChanges", Con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter NewSysChangeVersionParam = new SqlParameter("@NewSysChangeVersion", SqlDbType.Int);
            NewSysChangeVersion.Value = (object)NewSysChangeVersion ?? DBNull.Value;
            NewSysChangeVersion.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            NewSysChangeVersion.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt;
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int sdrreader = sdr.FieldCount;
            InventoryPushSubscriptionRecord rec = new InventoryPushSubscriptionRecord();


            while (sdr.Read())
            {

                inrec.InventoryPushSubscriptionId = sdr.GetInt32(0);
                inrec.SysChangeVersion = sdr.IsDBNull(1) ? (long?)null : sdr.GetInt64(1);
                inrec.InvDate = sdr.GetDateTime(2);
                inrec.ResortId = sdr.GetInt32(3);
                inrec.RoomType = sdr.GetString(4);
                inrec.InvCount = sdr.GetInt32(5);
                inrec.ResortName = sdr.GetString(6);


                Int64 NewSysChangeVersion;
                NewSysChangeVersion = Convert.ToInt64(rec.LastSysChangeVersion);
                int ResortId;
                ResortId = inrec.ResortId;
                string RoomType;
                RoomType = inrec.RoomType;
                int avail = inrec.InvCount;
                DateTime frodte = inrec.InvDate;
                DateTime todte = inrec.InvDate;
                int NoofRatePackages = sdrreader;
                Int32 InventoryPushSubscriptionId;
                InventoryPushSubscriptionId = inrec.InventoryPushSubscriptionId;
                Int64 NewLastSysChangeVersion;
                NewLastSysChangeVersion = Convert.ToInt64(inrec.SysChangeVersion);
                if (NewSysChangeVersion != null)
                {
                    sendUpdate(NewSysChangeVersion, ResortId, RoomType, avail, frodte, todte, NoofRatePackages, InventoryPushSubscriptionId, NewLastSysChangeVersion);
                }
            }

            //    sdr.Close();
            //    sdr.Dispose();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
```

**Updated**
               eventLog1.WriteEntry("exception"); 
               throw;
            }
        }

Comment: I suspect that to get any insight from the community you'll have to share the content of `RunApp`, since that's where the failure occurs.  An exception in `RunApp` might cause your log not to be written...

Comment: So do you get those two messages in the eventlog? If so you posted the wrong code. If not you never started the service or you posted the wrong code.

Comment: Ok but the last time I placed my code on one of my questions I was told it was too long and nobody wanted to scroll through it....I will edit my question to include the code, @Tony Hopkinson my event log shows"Windows service 3 has started, running App" and nothing else after that.

Comment: Added portions from RunApp() thanks

Comment: Why not add a line in the catch statement to log whatever the error is?

Comment: So you are swallowing any exceptions. Well I guess you just learned why that's a really bad idea. put th exception details in the event log at least. I'm going to take a wild guess at the user the service is running as doesn't have access to the db though.

Comment: I have Updated my question after reconfiguring my code. I can now confirm that it is not the timer as I have changed the start() and stop() to properly run the timer. Inside of my RunApp() I have set the log to print exception. Now every 15seconds I get exception in my logs. Would be grateful for any sort of insight to where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Might be worth logging the actual exception details, rather than just "exception"

Comment: @iridium can you please tell me how to do that. I don't know and everyone keep saying but no one's really telling me how. Would be grateful for an example or sample or something

Comment: You need to log the data from the exception message (ex.Message) which will tell you what error occurred, and also the exception's stack trace ("ex.StackTrace") which will tell you where it occurred.

Comment: Thanks Iridium please place your comment as an answer to my question so that I can mark and close this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editted my exception as advised.

catch (Exception ex)
            {

```
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.StackTrace);
            throw;

        }
```